# R: for-loops or lapply to some elements of a named list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, apply, lapply

For example, I have a `config.R` file with model parameters, that look like this:

```
var1 = "Fruit"
var2 = "Vegetables"
country = c("BRAZIL", "ECUADOR", "Georgia")
flag = NULL
peak = 30
years = c(2010, 2020)
remove1 = c("Bananas_ZZ_100s", "Apple_150-300_Pk", "Mango_mono")
remove2 = c("Tomato_ZR_400s", "cabbage300_Pk")
```

Then, I load the config file:

```
params = new.env()
source("config/config.R", params)
params = mget(ls(params), envir = params)
```

and get the named list with parameters:

```
> print(params)

$var1 
[1] "Fruit"

$var2 
[1] "Vegetables"

$country
[1] "BRAZIL"    "ECUADOR"    "Georgia"
```

etc.

**I want to convert character variables in my params list in lowercase, except for two variables: remove1 and remove2**

I was able to convert **all** character variables in the list in this way:

```
  params = lapply(params, function(params) {
  if (is.character(params)) return(tolower(params))
  else return(params)
  })
```

but I don’t know how to apply this function (or maybe with `for` loops) to all characters var. excluding several variables.

I will be very grateful for any help!

P.S. **what I want to get:**

```
> print(params)

$var1 
[1] "fruit"

$var2 
[1] "vegetables"

$country
[1] "brazil"  "ecuador"  "georgia" 

$flag
NULL

$peak
[1] 30

$years
[1] 2010   2020

$remove1
[1] "Bananas_ZZ_100s"   "Apple_150-300_Pk"   "Mango_mono"

$remove2
[1] "Tomato_ZR_400s"   "cabbage300_Pk"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need both names and value in the list, we can use `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) if(is.character(x) & !y %in% c('remove1', 'remove2'))
                   tolower(x) else x, params, names(params))


#country
#[1] "brazil"  "ecuador" "georgia"

#$flag
#NULL

#$peak
#[1] 30

#$remove1
#[1] "Bananas_ZZ_100s"  "Apple_150-300_Pk" "Mango_mono"      

#$remove2
#[1] "Tomato_ZR_400s" "cabbage300_Pk" 

#$var1
#[1] "fruit"

#$var2
#[1] "vegetables"

#$years
#[1] 2010 2020
```

It maybe easier with `purrr::imap`

```
purrr::imap(params, ~if(is.character(.x) & !.y %in% c('remove1', 'remove2'))  
                     tolower(.x) else .x)
```

---

You can also first find out elements that we need to change and then apply `tolower` on them.

```
inds <- !names(params) %in% c('remove1', 'remove2') & sapply(params, is.character)
params[inds] <- lapply(params[inds], tolower)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if it helps?

```
params <- list(
  var1 = "Fruit",
  var2 = "Vegetables",
  country = c("BRAZIL", "ECUADOR", "Georgia"),
  flag = NULL,
  peak = 30,
  years = c(2010, 2020),
  remove1 = c("Bananas_ZZ_100s", "Apple_150-300_Pk", "Mango_mono"),
  remove2 = c("Tomato_ZR_400s", "cabbage300_Pk"))

# list of params to exclude from tolower check
exclude <- alist(remove1=, remove2=)

# create an unnamed list with the correct params lowered
params.lower <- lapply(names(params), function (name) {

  # if the name of the param is not in the exculsion list and the value is character
  if (!name %in% names(exclude) && is.character(params[[name]])) {

    # return the lower case value of the param
    tolower(params[[name]]) 

  } else { 

    # return the value of the param unchanged
    params[[name]]
  }
})

# assign the param names to the new list
names(params.lower) <- names(params)

params.lower
#$var1
#[1] "fruit"

#$var2
#[1] "vegetables"

#$country
#[1] "brazil"  "ecuador" "georgia"

#$flag
#NULL

#$peak
#[1] 30

#$years
#[1] 2010 2020

#$remove1
#[1] "Bananas_ZZ_100s"  "Apple_150-300_Pk" "Mango_mono"      

#$remove2
#[1] "Tomato_ZR_400s" "cabbage300_Pk"
```